# some files generated by vxworks dosfs (fat32) can't be seen in windows7

Tags: vxworks

The embedded system has a portable disk(with fat32 file system) and running vxworks with DosFS to create and write the files on the disk. some times(occasionally), the files on the disk generated by the system can't be seen from windows 7. while in Vxworks shell, using the command "ll" can show the files.

what happened?

Comment: Are the files visible from Windows 7 after you've executed the `ll` command? ... I've had the problem once that the FAT entries where not flushed which caused some weird effects. Try calling `statfs(..)` before accessing you target from Windows ... maybe this improves things. Additionally I've found that the Windows FTP client implementation sometimes gets confused from the VxWorks server response which may result in files size of 0, wrong file names and/or missing files.

Comment: Thx 4 your sharing. They are still invisible from win7 after the ll command. An interesting thing is    the output of the ll command shows that the files(have problems) are sorted and showed as the last ones in the output list, no matter what the creating times and filenames .